# Webrtc Android and iOS Black screen issue

Tags: android, ios, swift, kotlin, webrtc

I am using the google stun server in both android and iOS. For data communication using the firebase. I am able to connect android to android video call and iOS to iOS video call. But while connect the android to iOS and iOS to android it show the remote video as black screen

iOS code

```
  let configuration = RTCConfiguration()
        configuration.iceServers = [
            RTCIceServer(urlStrings: [
                "stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302", "stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302"
            ])
        ]
```

```
  private let factory: RTCPeerConnectionFactory = {
        let videoEncoderFactory = RTCSimluatorVideoEncoderFactory()
        let videoDecoderFactory = RTCSimulatorVideoDecoderFactory()
        print(videoEncoderFactory)
        videoEncoderFactory.preferredCodec =  RTCVideoCodecInfo(name: kRTCVideoCodecVp8Name)
        return RTCPeerConnectionFactory(encoderFactory: videoEncoderFactory, decoderFactory: videoDecoderFactory)
    }()
```

```
   videoSource!.adaptOutputFormat(toWidth: 1280, height: 720, fps: 30)
        videoCapturer = RTCCameraVideoCapturer(delegate: videoSource!)
        localVideoTrack = factory.videoTrack(with: videoSource!, trackId: "local_track")
        localAudioTrack = factory.audioTrack(with: audioSource, trackId: "local_track" + "_audio")
        localAudioTrack.isEnabled = true
        
//        audioSource.volume = 1
        super.init()
        
        let constraints = RTCMediaConstraints(mandatoryConstraints: nil,
                                              optionalConstraints: ["DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement": kRTCMediaConstraintsValueTrue])
        peerConnection = factory.peerConnection(with: configuration, constraints: constraints, delegate: self)
        peerConnection?.add(localVideoTrack, streamIds: ["local_track"])
        peerConnection?.add(localAudioTrack,streamIds: ["local_track"])
        remoteVideoTrack = peerConnection?.transceivers.first { $0.mediaType == .video }?.receiver.track as? RTCVideoTrack
```

Android code

```
private val iceServer = listOf(
        PeerConnection.IceServer.builder("stun:stun.l.google.com:19302")
                .createIceServer(),
                PeerConnection.IceServer.builder("stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302")
            .createIceServer()

)
```

```
private fun initPeerConnectionFactory(context: Application) {
    val options = PeerConnectionFactory.InitializationOptions.builder(context)
            .setEnableInternalTracer(true)
            .setFieldTrials("WebRTC-H264HighProfile/Enabled/")
            .createInitializationOptions()
    PeerConnectionFactory.initialize(options)
}
```

```
private fun buildPeerConnectionFactory(): PeerConnectionFactory {
    return PeerConnectionFactory
            .builder()
            .setVideoDecoderFactory(DefaultVideoDecoderFactory(rootEglBase.eglBaseContext))
            .setVideoEncoderFactory(DefaultVideoEncoderFactory(rootEglBase.eglBaseContext, true, true))
            .setOptions(PeerConnectionFactory.Options().apply {
                disableEncryption = false
                disableNetworkMonitor = true

            })
            .createPeerConnectionFactory()
}
```

```
  fun startLocalVideoCapture(localVideoOutput: SurfaceViewRenderer) {
        val surfaceTextureHelper = SurfaceTextureHelper.create(Thread.currentThread().name, rootEglBase.eglBaseContext)
        (videoCapturer as VideoCapturer).initialize(surfaceTextureHelper, localVideoOutput.context, localVideoSource.capturerObserver)
        videoCapturer.startCapture(1280, 720, 60)
        localAudioTrack = peerConnectionFactory.createAudioTrack(LOCAL_TRACK_ID + "_audio", audioSource);
        localVideoTrack = peerConnectionFactory.createVideoTrack(LOCAL_TRACK_ID, localVideoSource)
        localVideoTrack?.addSink(localVideoOutput)
        val localStream = peerConnectionFactory.createLocalMediaStream(LOCAL_STREAM_ID)
        localStream.addTrack(localVideoTrack)
      localStream.addTrack(localAudioTrack)

        peerConnection?.addStream(localStream)

    }
```

I need help for connecting android and ios without black screen in remote video

Android:

> v=0o=- 6563448285196734461 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1s=-t=0 0a=group:BUNDLE audio videoa=msid-semantic: WMSm=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 97 98 100 101 127 124 125c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0a=ice-ufrag:I69Ta=ice-pwd:RY4fL2nYEJVHJ1vDc7fsws0qa=ice-options:trickle renominationa=fingerprint:sha-256 91:33:FC:D0:9C:BD:FE:A8:F4:7D:8F:6E:1F:71:05:4F:5B:F3:A0:DA:86:14:8A:CA:29:F0:45:AB:88:02:EE:50a=setup:activea=mid:audioa=extmap:14 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffseta=extmap:2 `http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time`a=extmap:13 urn:3gpp:video-orientationa=extmap:3 `http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01`a=extmap:12 `http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay`a=extmap:11 `http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-content-type`a=extmap:7 `http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-timing`a=extmap:9 `http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/color-spacea=recvonly`a=rtcp-muxa=rtcp-rsizea=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remba=rtcp-fb:96 transport-cca=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fira=rtcp-fb:96 nacka=rtcp-fb:96 nack plia=rtpmap:97 rtx/90000a=fmtp:97 apt=96a=rtpmap:98 H264/90000a=rtcp-fb:98 goog-remba=rtcp-fb:98 transport-cca=rtcp-fb:98 ccm fira=rtcp-fb:98 nacka=rtcp-fb:98 nack plia=fmtp:98 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=640c1fa=rtpmap:100 H264/90000a=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remba=rtcp-fb:100 transport-cca=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fira=rtcp-fb:100 nacka=rtcp-fb:100 nack plia=fmtp:100 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01fa=rtpmap:101 rtx/90000a=fmtp:101 apt=100a=rtpmap:127 red/90000a=rtpmap:124 rtx/90000a=fmtp:124 apt=127a=rtpmap:125 ulpfec/90000m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 102 0 8 106 105 13 110 112 113 126c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0a=ice-ufrag:I69Ta=ice-pwd:RY4fL2nYEJVHJ1vDc7fsws0qa=ice-options:trickle renominationa=fingerprint:sha-256 91:33:FC:D0:9C:BD:FE:A8:F4:7D:8F:6E:1F:71:05:4F:5B:F3:A0:DA:86:14:8A:CA:29:F0:45:AB:88:02:EE:50a=setup:activea=mid:videoa=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-levela=extmap:2 `http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time`a=extmap:3 `http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01`a=recvonlya=rtcp-muxa=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cca=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000a=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000a=rtpmap:102 ILBC/8000a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000a=rtpmap:106 CN/32000a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000a=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000a=rtpmap:112 telephone-event/32000a=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000

iOS

> v=0o=- 8886095848359872555 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1s=-t=0 0a=group:BUNDLE audio videoa=msid-semantic: WMS local_trackm=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 97 98 99 100 101 127 124 125c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0a=ice-ufrag:1BBja=ice-pwd:uaFw/ANPPPKHdZmf+qr31phba=ice-options:trickle renominationa=fingerprint:sha-256 1B:D0:0D:16:73:CD:FF:B9:F5:C3:8E:86:3D:83:DF:5D:3D:40:86:B1:67:D5:D3:9D:A4:92:AA:0F:C6:09:AE:ECa=setup:actpassa=mid:audioa=extmap:14 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffseta=extmap:2 `http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time`a=extmap:13 urn:3gpp:video-orientationa=extmap:3 `http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01`a=extmap:12 `http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay`a=extmap:11 `http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-content-type`a=extmap:7 `http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-timing`a=extmap:8 `http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-avtext-framemarking-07`a=extmap:9 `http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/color-space`a=extmap:4 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mida=extmap:5 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:rtp-stream-ida=extmap:6 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:repaired-rtp-stream-ida=sendrecva=msid:local_track local_tracka=rtcp-muxa=rtcp-rsizea=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remba=rtcp-fb:96 transport-cca=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fira=rtcp-fb:96 nacka=rtcp-fb:96 nack plia=rtpmap:97 rtx/90000a=fmtp:97 apt=96a=rtpmap:98 H264/90000a=rtcp-fb:98 goog-remba=rtcp-fb:98 transport-cca=rtcp-fb:98 ccm fira=rtcp-fb:98 nacka=rtcp-fb:98 nack plia=fmtp:98 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=640c1fa=rtpmap:99 rtx/90000a=fmtp:99 apt=98a=rtpmap:100 H264/90000a=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remba=rtcp-fb:100 transport-cca=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fira=rtcp-fb:100 nacka=rtcp-fb:100 nack plia=fmtp:100 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01fa=rtpmap:101 rtx/90000a=fmtp:101 apt=100a=rtpmap:127 red/90000a=rtpmap:124 rtx/90000a=fmtp:124 apt=127a=rtpmap:125 ulpfec/90000a=ssrc-group:FID 1956454411 1435441277a=ssrc:1956454411 cname:BnVPai9gO/G5EEuLa=ssrc:1956454411 msid:local_track local_tracka=ssrc:1956454411 mslabel:local_tracka=ssrc:1956454411 label:local_tracka=ssrc:1435441277 cname:BnVPai9gO/G5EEuLa=ssrc:1435441277 msid:local_track local_tracka=ssrc:1435441277 mslabel:local_tracka=ssrc:1435441277 label:local_trackm=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 102 0 8 106 105 13 110 112 113 126c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0a=ice-ufrag:1BBja=ice-pwd:uaFw/ANPPPKHdZmf+qr31phba=ice-options:trickle renominationa=fingerprint:sha-256 1B:D0:0D:16:73:CD:FF:B9:F5:C3:8E:86:3D:83:DF:5D:3D:40:86:B1:67:D5:D3:9D:A4:92:AA:0F:C6:09:AE:ECa=setup:actpassa=mid:videoa=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-levela=extmap:2 `http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time`a=extmap:3 `http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01`a=extmap:4 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mida=extmap:5 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:rtp-stream-ida=extmap:6 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:repaired-rtp-stream-ida=sendrecva=msid:local_track local_track_audioa=rtcp-muxa=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cca=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000a=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000a=rtpmap:102 ILBC/8000a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000a=rtpmap:106 CN/32000a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000a=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000a=rtpmap:112 telephone-event/32000a=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000a=ssrc:2967951894 cname:BnVPai9gO/G5EEuLa=ssrc:2967951894 msid:local_track local_track_audioa=ssrc:2967951894 mslabel:local_tracka=ssrc:2967951894 label:local_track_audio

Comment: Could you please compare the SDP of both the clients(Android and iOS) or Add SDP in your question

Comment: @Daljeet I have the both android and ios sdp in the post can you please help

Comment: please confirm Audio is fine? And both Android and iOS is not able to see the video? or its on the one side only

Comment: both audio and video is not working. Both android and ios not able to see the video. but android to android working fine and also ios to ios working fine. We also getting the handshake response everything fine in the firebase @Daljeet

Comment: If you able to connect but not able to send/receive audio/video then seems like SDP negotiation issue between two clients. To debug further I would suggest compare SDP offer/answer when two android clients connects. And same with two iOS clients. Look what is missing. We may be succeed or fail in this approach but one way to move further. Would like to know if you able to fix.

Comment: Okay sure thanks will try to fix it @Daljeet

Comment: Looks like I have an almost same issue, but little bit different.
Android-Android, iOS-iOS, Android-iOS, all works, but any mobile could not connect to Web App, regardless Caller or Answerer
any ideas?